# Vue.js, how to add/modify css class inside slot from parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I've been trying crack this simple logic and yet failed, I really need your help.
Well what I'm trying to achieve is to add or modify the class name inside slot.

```
// Parent component
<div class="col">
  <slider>
    <slide v-for="intro in compOpts.blockIntro">
      <block-intro :compOpts="{ props: { wrapper: true, bg: false } }">
        <p v-html="intro.title"></p>
        <div slot="content" v-html="intro.content" class="blockIntro__content"></div>
      </block-intro>
    </slide>
  </slider>
</div>

// Slider component
<div class="slider__container">
  <slot></slot>
</div>

// Slide component
<div>
 <slot></slot>
</div>

// BlockIntro component
<div class="col--h100" :class="{ 'bg--darkDark': compOpts.props.bg, 'col': !compOpts.props.wrapper }"> << --- Add visible class here from Slider component
<div class="col col__blockIntro" :class="{ 'col__blockIntro--spaced': compOpts.props.spaced }">
  <div class="col col__blockIntro__introQuote">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
  <slot name="content"></slot>
</div>
```

```
<div class="col--h100" :class="{ 'bg--darkDark': compOpts.props.bg, 'col': !compOpts.props.wrapper }"> << --- Add visible class here from Slider component
```

component hierarchy

```
-> Slider
--> Slide
---> BlockIntro
```

My Slot component is giving me the BlockIntro component template and div.col--h100 is the first/parent child element inside Slider. Now I'm trying to add an visible class to div.col--h100 from the Slider component. I consoled the Vnode using $slots but can't change the value in $slots.$elm.className

Please help.

P.S. I'm a newbie in Vue, so please forgive me if my structure is wrong

P.S. I think I couldn't explain myself clearly. So what I'm looking forward to achieve is to implement the following carousel in Vue2

https://codepen.io/smitray/pen/qjXGZp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a first pass conversion of the slideshow you linked to Vue. Notice that I use a scoped slot to pass methods components contained in the slots. Hopefully you can use this to get some ideas.

Some immediate improvements that could be worked on

- Use Vue transitions

```js
console.clear()

const slideData = [
  {
    url:"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/waterfall-free-stock-photo-244915.jpg",
    backgroundColor:"green"
  },
  {
    url:"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/free-stock-photos-1.jpg",
    backgroundColor:"orange"
  },
  {
    url: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/snowy-winter-vignette-bokeh-night-snow-falling-free-stock-photo.jpg",
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }

]

Vue.component("slideshow",{
  template: `
    <div class="container">
      <ul id="slides">
        <slot name="slides" :register="registerSlide" :active="activeSlide">
          {{registerSlide}}
        </slot>
      </ul>
      <slot :pause="pause" 
            :play="playSlideshow" 
            :next="nextSlide"
            :prev="previousSlide"
            name="controls">
      </slot>
    </div>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      slides:[],
      currentSlide: 0,
      playing: false,
      slideInterval: null,
      controls: null,
      activeSlide: null
    }
  },
  methods:{
    pause(){
      clearInterval(this.slideInterval)
    },
    registerSlide(slide){
      this.slides.push(slide)
    },
    goToSlide(n){
      this.currentSlide = (n+this.slides.length)%this.slides.length;
      this.activeSlide = this.slides[this.currentSlide]
    },
    nextSlide(){
      this.goToSlide(this.currentSlide+1);
    },
    previousSlide(){
      this.goToSlide(this.currentSlide-1);
    },
    playSlideshow(){
      this.playing = true;
      this.slideInterval = setInterval(this.nextSlide,2000);
    }

  },
  mounted(){
    if (this.slides.length > 0){
      this.activeSlide = this.slides[this.currentSlide]
      this.playSlideshow()
    }
  }
})

Vue.component("slide",{
  props:["slide", "register", "active"],
  template:`
    <li class="slide" :class="slideClass" :style="slideStyle"></li>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      showing: false,
      isSlide: true
    }
  },
  computed:{
    slideClass(){
      return {
        showing: this.active === this,
      }
    },
    slideStyle(){
      return {
        'background-image': `url(${this.slide.url})`,
        'background-color': this.slide.backgroundColor     
      }
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    console.log(this.$props)
    this.register(this)
  }
})

Vue.component("slide-controls", {
  props:["pause", "play", "next", "prev"],
  template:`
  <div class="buttons" style="top: 10px; left: 10px">
    <button @click="prev" class="controls" id="previous">&lt;</button>
    <button @click="onPause" class="controls" id="pause">{{paused ? '&#9658;' : '&#10074;&#10074;'}}</button>
    <button @click="next" class="controls" id="next">&gt;</button>
  </div>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      isControls: true,
      paused: false
    }
  },
  methods:{
    onPause(){
      this.paused = !this.paused
      if (this.paused)
        this.pause()
      else
        this.play()
    }
  }
})


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    slides: slideData,
  }
})
```

```css
/*
essential styles:
these make the slideshow work
*/
#slides{
 position: relative;
 height: 300px;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
}

.slide{
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 1;

 -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
 -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
 -o-transition: opacity 1s;
 transition: opacity 1s;
}

.showing{
 opacity: 1;
 z-index: 2;
}




/*
non-essential styles:
just for appearance; change whatever you want
*/

.slide{
 font-size: 40px;
 padding: 40px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background: #333;
 color: #fff;
  
  background-size: cover;
}



.controls{
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
  width: 70px;
}

.controls:hover,
.controls:focus{
  background: #eee;
  color: #333;
}

.container{
  position: relative;
}

.buttons{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <slideshow>
    <template slot="slides" scope="props">
      <slide v-for="slide in slides" 
             :slide="slide"
             v-bind="props">
      </slide>
    </template>
    <template slot="controls" scope="props">
      <slide-controls v-bind="props"></slide-controls>
    </template>
  </slideshow>
</div>
```

Comment: So, considering the codepen's link, how can I really implement this concept. Honestly, it's not very much clear to me.

Comment: @SmitRay Do you have a pen with your current version in Vue? Where you are asking how to pass a value a slot? I assume you have something in order to ask that particular question.

Comment: passing a value in a slot isn't the problem. What I need is to add a css class on an element inside the component template.

Comment: @SmitRay Updated.

Comment: This is awesome. Just what I needed. I'd upvote 10 times if I could for this solution. Thanks a lot bro.

Comment: hi, hope you're doing great. So, I'm writing this to you as I'm stuck again. You mentioned about implementing vue transition and I've been trying to do so. Tried with transition-group but no luck. Can you please give me some idea. I really appreciate the help you already did and I'm asking for more, I'm sorry but I really need it.

Comment: @SmitRay I'm not terribly familiar with transitions, which is why I didn't do it myself. Maybe open a new question with that specific issue.